# AngularJS app not running correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS.  I'm trying to run a simple example from a book, but it's not working correctly, and I can't figure out why.

This code runs fine:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="HelloController">
        <input ng-model="greeting.text"/>
        <p>{{greeting.text}}, World!</p>
    </div>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script>
             function HelloController($scope) {
                 $scope.greeting = {text: 'Hello'};
             }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

But this is the code I'm having problems with

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller='CartController'>
    <h1>Your Order</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <span>{{item.title}}</span>
        <input ng-model="item.quantity">
        <span>{{item.price| currency}}</span>
        <span>{{item.price * item.quantity| currency}}</span>
        <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
    </div>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script>
                function CartController($scope) {
                    $scope.items = [
                        {title: 'Paint pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
                        {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 17, price: 12.95},
                        {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 6.95}
                    ];
                    $scope.remove = function(index) {
                        $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
                    };
                }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Expecting this output:

[image]

But getting this output:

[image]

I don't understand why I'm not getting the data output, and why it's not repeating.  Basically, why the example is not running.  I copy and paste the code straight from the book.

Comment: What are you including angular.js twice?

Comment: move the controller code out of the controller

Comment: Remove the app name from `ng-app`, or run a `.configure` statement before your controller. Also, check your console, there's most likely a nice descriptive error there.

Comment: @Richard Dalton Forgot to remove that from the code. That doesn't fix the problem though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you write `ng-app='myApp'` you are saying to angular that exists a module named `myApp` somewhere.

Just add this line before your controllers definition:

`var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);`

You can see the docs [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) and [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp)

Answer (score 6):

You should define your `myApp` module:

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
    <title>Your Shopping Cart</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller='CartController'>
    <h1>Your Order</h1>
    <div ng-repeat='item in items'>
        <span>{{item.title}}</span>
        <input ng-model='item.quantity'>
        <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
        <span>{{item.price * item.quantity | currency}}</span>
        <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
    </div>
    <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('CartController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.items = [
                {title: 'Paint pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
                {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 17, price: 12.95},
                {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 6.95}
            ];
            $scope.remove = function(index) {
                $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but including `angular.js` only once could help, too.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also add the namespace:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
```

Even though, adding the module is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Give the name of app as html ng-app="myapp" in html file  and then add/define the module into the controller as 
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced this problem, resolved it by invoking module creation scope before controller js . Also ensure module is created in script or js file.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Shopping Cart</title>
<script src="angular-1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])

myApp.controller('CartController', function($scope) {
            $scope.items = [
            {title: 'Paint pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
            {title: 'Polka Dots', quantity: 17, price: 12.95},
            {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 6.95}
        ];

    $scope.remove = function(index){
        $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
    };
});
</script>   
</head>
<body ng-controller="CartController">
<h1>Your order</h1>

<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span>{{item.title}}</span>
    <input ng-model="item.quantity" />
    <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
    <span>{{item.price * item.quantity | currency}}</span>
    <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```